# Head pointer and Next pointer in Linked list in python

Tags: python, pointers, linked-list, singly-linked-list

How does the head and next attribute hold address without even explicitly declaring them as pointers in the [singly linked list program](https://medium.com/@kojinoshiba/data-structures-in-python-series-1-linked-lists-d9f848537b4d) python

Answer (score 0):

In Python, variables are just names for objects.  An object can have zero or more names.  So if you have a simple class like:

```
class Node:
    def __init__(self,value):
        self.value = value
        self.next = None
```

You can create nodes and "name" the next one in the list:

```
>>> a = Node(1)
>>> b = Node(2)
>>> a.next = b    # a.next is another name for b
>>>
>>> b.value
2
>>> a.next.value
2
>>> b.value = 5     # change b
>>> a.next.value    # a.next another name for b
5
```

Internally, at least in CPython, The names refer to `PyObject*` instances, which *are* pointers.

Comment: Hi, Thank you for the answer. However, what I don't understand is how does python compiler know that the instance variable 'next' has to store address and that the instance variable 'value' has to store the numerical value without explicitly mentioning so.

Comment: @Preethi everything in Python is an object. In CPython, Everything is derived from PyObject and had an address. Every variable stores the address of the object it referenced. The variable doesn’t “know” what the object type is...the object itself knows.